# Added MathNet.Numerics as reference, but the executable says could not load the refernce file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reference, .net-assembly

I'm very new to this, C# WinForm is my first project whatsoever... Bear with me if my question is not clear. Feel free to ask me to clarify it.

I have a C# WinForm application that use MathNet.Numerics and MathNet.Numerics.IO as references I added these two reference from the Package Manager Console by typing in PM> Install-Package MathNet.Numerics

It works on my desktop: these two references show up under the References folder, when I Build Solution, two .dll files also show up in the Debug folder. But when I copy & pasted the executable to another computer, it says "Could not load file or assembly "MathNet.Numerics, Version=2.6.1.30. Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or one if its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please tell me how to add these references to the executable file so that it can be used on other computers.

Comment: You need to copy the .dll files as well.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send the dll as well to whomever you are sending your project and in case of database or anything like that follow below thing:-

in the properties of both the dll files under refernce folder make "Copy always" option clicked it will copy the reference in your case!!

Comment: For both .dll files, I selected "True" for the "Copy Local" option. VS says Copy Local indicates whether the reference will be copied to the output directory. I thought this could solve it, but actually not...

Comment: But you also have to deploy these all files on your deployment machine. I mean, references and references of your references

Comment: yeah agree @T.S. ..you have to deploy all the files!! can u tell me how you are copying to another machine i mean whole solution or installer or how?

Comment: I copied the entire Debug folder to the deployment computer. It works now! I'll test which file I can remove from the deploy folder to make it look cleaner. But at least it works now. Thanks you all!